# Automatic Backups using Filezilla

Tags: windows, backup, filezilla, vps

I've lost loads of information caused by HDD errors or viruses.
I have a Dedicated Server, and I would like to have an automated backup system using FileZilla. I want it to backup a certain directory every day.

How do I do it?

Comment: What operating system are you using? (on both local and remote computer)

Comment: Dedicate Server is Windows 2008 S1, and the Ftp Server is my webhosting cpanel

Comment: Please note that FTP is insecure and you should be using SSH/SCP instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How to Automatically Backup Your Web Server Files With WinSCP over FTP](http://www.howtogeek.com/100918/how-to-automatically-backup-your-web-server-files-with-winscp-over-ftp/) article may help you to Backup your data on the FTP server to your Computer, but it won't use FileZilla. Anyway, it can be useful.

[Backing up your data to FTP](http://www.documentbackup.com/help/backup-to-ftp.html) article can help you to set a scheduler and take a backup of your data that are on your HDD and send your data to an FTP Server.

Comment: That backups the data from the ftpserver to your computer. I want backup the data from the computer to the ftpserver (cpanel).

Comment: Ok. i edited my Answer. see it again.

Comment: That isn't automatic.

Comment: I tested it and its a fine application. you should set the settings on Scheduler Tab, so it can backup your data as scheduled options.

Comment: It's working now thanks, is there any crack for this? Because it is 30-days free trial

Comment: Now, its working :) just you have to hold the application Process.  if you want to test it, you can easily set the scheduler as less time and check scheduler works or not. it must Works usually.

Comment: It's working now thanks, is there any crack for this? Because it is 30-days free trial

Comment: Sorry, you have to Buy it. Cracking any programs and products are against the Copy-Right laws. also you can get crack by searching IF there is no copy-right laws your country (If so, its Never recommended)

Comment: Ok, do you have skype?

Comment: No, i don't have. if you want it for Crack, i'll sorry.

Comment: @RechardAlfonso also it a Answer was Helped you to fix your problem, make it as "Accepted Answer"

Comment: or maybe not...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct option of doing such thing with FileZilla.
Try contacting your dedicated server company, they probably have a way of doing backups.

Comment: They haven't...

Answer (score 1):

I use and would suggest [Duplicati](http://www.duplicati.com/) for FTP backups. It's "a free backup client that securely stores encrypted, incremental, compressed backups on cloud storage services and remote file servers." I also successfully use [Cobian Backup](http://www.cobiansoft.com/cobianbackup.htm).

Comment: Is it an automated backup system?

Comment: @RichardAlfonso, if you mean can you schedule backups, Yes.

Comment: What is shedule?

Comment: @Richard Alfonso, daily, weekly, monthly, and at a specific time of day...

Comment: Ah ok thanks, well the program crashes when I open it.. Do you know any other program?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is use the [Cobian Backup](http://www.cobiansoft.com/index.htm) Software, it's free and can backup all data automatically to a remote FTP.

I use it to backup servers and desktop computers, and works fine. Have a lot of options.

Comment: Can you add more information to your answer, specifically, how to use the software in a way that answers the askers question? Also, the asker asked about Filezilla. Why is this solution better?